# How to use a user defined range in a formula in vba

Tags: excel, vba, range, formula

I am trying to define a range starting at B2 (constant) to the last cell with data which will change month to month.  I want to take the same range length and define another range for column A which will also start at A2 (constant) but will extend only down as far as column B goes.  I'm trying to identify them as range and use the dimmed range in a formula in vba but it doesn't like it...any ideas?

```
Dim Data As range
Dim Time As range
range("b2").Select
'Select Range

Set Data = range("B2", range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set Time("A2", range("A2").End(xlDown))
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],.address(data),.address(time):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"
```

Comment: Is the typo in your code too? Or just on SO: `Set Time("A2", range("A2").End(xlDown))`, should be `Set Time = Range("A2",...)`. But as I mentioned, I'd change `Time` to say `timeRng`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the formula string, add the address, and then continue:

```
"=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],.address(" & data.address & "),.address(" & 
time.address & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"
```

Note since you're using R1C1 style, you might have to do this on both `.address` parts,

```
time.address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

so:

```
"=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],.address(" & data.address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "),.address(" & 
time.address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"
```

Edit: Also, I would change the keyword `Time`, as I think that's a reserved word. Perhaps `Dim timeRng as Range`?

Comment: Dim Data As range
    Dim Time As range
    
    Set Data = range("B2", range("B2").End(xlDown))
    Set Time = Data.Offset(columnOffset:=-1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],.address(" & data.address & "),.address(" &
    time.address & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"
    End Sub

Comment: i made the changes above (I can't figure out how to post with the proper formatting...sorry).  It kicks up a an error for syntax now.

Comment: @FrankCicconeII - What error? Did you try adding the `ReferenceStyle`?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what the reference style means or how to implement...Also in reference to specifying which sheets i intentionally left it undefined since i want to be able to use this macro on multiple tabs.

Comment: @FrankCicconeII - see my edit. Also, if that's the case, make SURE that you qualify your ranges with the worksheet, and [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Sorry i don't think i'm understanding what should look different...i did change to rngTime FYI.  Does this line look right to you?  it's all that VBA doesn't like...

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],.address(" & data.address & "),.address(" &
rngtime.address & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"

Comment: also for what it's worth, i don't think it's picking up my reference to DIMs since it's not capitalizing to "rngTime" and "Data" as i set my dims to do so...

Comment: I think i've incorporated every edit but still get the object required error...

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],.address(" & Data.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "),.address(" & Time.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"

Comment: @FrankCicconeII - You're missing the variables before `.address`

Comment: so are you saying it should be this instead?

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ "=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],data.address(" & Data.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "),time.address(" & Time.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @BruceWayne's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69529698/6609896), to address the first part of your question:

If I have a range B2:B50, and I want the corresponding A column, then I can use the Offset function:

```
Set time = data.Offset(columnOffset:=-1)
```

Alternatively you can construct the column like this:

```
Set time = Sheet1.Range("A2").Resize(Rows(data), 1) 'nrows, 1 column
```

Then you could put A2 anywhere

---

FWIW:

- `range("b2").Select` [is unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6609896) and will really slow down your code if you get into this habit (it's just because the macro recorder doesn't know what you want exactly). You could use `Range("B2").Offset(1,1).FormulaR1C1` with no selecting
- You can name cells in excel and refer to the names: `Range("myNamedCell")`
- Always best practice to prepend the sheet name and fully qualify references (e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1")`) since that will always refer to the same cell, whereas `Range("A1")` refers to A1 on whichever sheet happens to be selected when you run the macro

Comment: Thank you both for your help...I think I figured it out gleaning from both sets of responses...it should be:

Comment: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=FORECAST.ETS([@Timeline],(" & Data.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "),(" & rngTime.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "):R[-1]C[-2],1,0)"